# DataGrid inside Datagrid virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, nested

I need to create a DataGrid inside a DataGrid. It works but I have a problem with the virtualization.
With one DataGrid, the RowVirtualization works fine. Now, when I create a DataGrid inside a DataGrid, the virtualization from the inner datagrid doesn't work and it takes very long to load an item with many rows. I think the problem is the outer datagrid which loads one row completely and inside this row there is the datagrid with a lot of rows and the RowVirtualization doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the problem?

[image]

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TestsGroupsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding TestsGroupsViewModel}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            HeadersVisibility="None" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TestsGroups}" 
            SelectionMode="Extended" 
            SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" 
            GridLinesVisibility="None" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" 
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
            EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
            EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
            VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Pixel"
            >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DataGridsInside" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <dataGridInDataGrid:TestsGroupControl x:Name="TestsGroup" 
                                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" 
                                                            SelectionMode="Extended" 
                                                            SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                                                            GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" 
                                                            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                                                            EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                                                            EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                                                            VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                                                            VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                                                            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                                            VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Pixel"
                                                            />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: When the inner Datagrid comes into sight, it's created new each time. That slows your UI drastically, SInce there's much functionality behind it. The other thing is, when you scroll and have big items in height, your scrolling isn't smooth and will produce artefacts. WPF lets you do a lot, but it wants not much more than strings and pictures in a List.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try fixing the height of the inner datagrid.
That way only a portion of it would be displayed with scrolling enabled inside it.
This will allow virtualization of the inner datagrid since only a portion of it is rendered at a time and the rest would be dynamically rendered during scrolling and it will increase the speed with which your datagrid's are loaded.