# Virtualization of DataGrid inside ListBox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listbox, ui-virtualization, nested-controls

My layout:
[image]

Virtualization of outer `ListBox` works but for inner `DataGrid` does not. Probably because the outer `ListBox`contains `ScrollViewer` inside:

> The `ScrollViewer` provides a window onto its child content. The problem is that the child content is given unlimited *virtual* space. In this virtual space, the `DataGrid` renders itself at full size, with all of its child items on display.

Looks like there is no simple solution.
But I would like even a workaround. Maybe to limit the *virtual* space of outer `ScrollViewer` somehow?

Comment: try set `DataGrid.MaxHeight`. it will definitely restrcit the space of DataGrid. Btw, how do you detect that virtualization doesn't work for DG?

Comment: Really, `MaxHeight` worked, didn't expect something so simple would fix that.  
Thanks. Please, convert to answer I will mark it.  
Detected by rendering single `DataGrid` with `10000` rows inside `ListBox` and without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that ScrollViewer is the first to be blamed. ListBox uses StackPanel with Vertical orientation as ItemsPanel. And vertical StackPanel doesn't restrict height of child elements.

Instead of changing container space, restrict DataGrid size by setting `DataGrid.MaxHeight`, and StackPanel won't give it more height than that limit. And then ScrollViewer will be limited to total size of all DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Just found similar answer here [DataGrid inside Datagrid virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27277224/2346621)

> Can you try fixing the `height` of the inner `datagrid`. That way only a portion of it would be displayed with scrolling enabled inside it. This will allow virtualization of the inner `datagrid` since only a portion of it is rendered at a time and the rest would be dynamically rendered during scrolling and it will increase the speed with which your `datagrid's` are loaded.

If helped, please go by the link above and upvote his answer